# Large space between text and tables

Tags: spacing, floats

I'm seemingly seeing a lot of white space between the main body text and tables, perhaps because I am using a three part table.

[image]

I've included a picture of what I am seeing. You can see the sheer waste of white space between the main text body and the table. I was wondering if anyone knew of any obvious solutions to this?

Comment: More probably, you're using `\begin{figure}[H]`

Comment: @egreg But I'm dealing with a table?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote figure instead of table, but the problem is the same

Answer (score 1):

Several solutions:

1. If you're using `\begin{figure}[H]` as @egreg suggested, change [H] to [h];
2. Put `\raggedbottom` in the preamble.  Downside of this is that there can be more space than you'd like at the bottom of the pages;
3. Put `\allowdisplaybreaks` in the preamble.  This will help if you have long formulas by breaking them across pages, which you may or may not find objectionable.